# Casting Object to Object[][]

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, casting

I need to cast an object into a multidimensional array but can't figure out how to do it. The object might contain an array of any object (boolean[][], int[][], String[][] etc). Here is a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] b = new boolean[10][10];

    Object o = b;

    Object[][] multiArray = (Object[][])o;

    for(int i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need to cast an object into a multidimensional array" <-- you can't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boolean[][]` is an array of primitives, thus although arrays are covariant, since a `boolean` is not an `Object`, it gives you an error telling you the cast is illegal. You might want to use `Boolean[][]`. Also note that unboxing and boxing does not work on arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. A `boolean` is a primitive, not a reference type. So while an array (or multi-dimensional array) of `boolean` values is itself an `Object`, it's elements are still `boolean` values, not instances of `Object`.

If you want to have an array of objects, you would need to box the `boolean` values as `Boolean` objects.

Note that you can still write your code with loops without boxing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
        // Do something with b[i][j] as a boolean
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `boolean` to `Boolean`. Java can then cast `Boolean` to `Object` for you (as subclass and super class)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, noticing that the array of primitive `boolean` was replaced by an array of `Boolean` (same consideration for the other data types, e.g.: use `Integer` in place of `int`, etc.), which are object types and *can* be casted to `Object`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Boolean[][] b = new Boolean[10][10];
    // fill b with values

    Object[][] multiArray = new Object[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++) {
            multiArray[i][j] = b[i][j]; // no cast is needed
        }
    }

}
```